Failing Kubernetes Pod creation from Python script executed in Init Container?
Is it possible to fail/terminate pod creation from a Python script executed from an Init container?
Init container:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myapp-container
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ["python3", "/scripts/example.py"]

example.py
What would this Python script contain?

Thanks!


to fail/terminate pod creation from a Python script

Try:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  ...
  initContainers:
  - name: init-myservice
    ...
    command: ["python3", "-c", "import sys; sys.exit(1)"]

